# How to make my both query to a single query using subquery while taking negation of second query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, notin

My both SQL Queries are give below:-

1)

```
SELECT Pk_class_id 
FROM tbl_student 
JOIN tbl_class on tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id 
JOIN tbl_staff on tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id 
WHERE tbl_student.updated_at <= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

---

2)

```
SELECT Pk_class_id 
FROM tbl_student 
JOIN tbl_class on tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id 
JOIN tbl_staff on tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id 
WHERE tbl_staff.reg_time >= tbl_student.updated_at - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

---

Both queries are running without error, while what i need is to make it into a single query, like **(1+!2) i need the opposite of second query to be associated with first query.**

---

i tried to get the opposite result of second query like this:-

```
SELECT Pk_class_id 
FROM tbl_student 
JOIN tbl_class on tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id 
JOIN tbl_staff on tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id 
WHERE tbl_staff.reg_time 
**NOT IN**
(
SELECT Pk_class_id 
FROM tbl_student 
JOIN tbl_class on tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id 
JOIN tbl_staff on tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id 
WHERE  tbl_staff.reg_time >= tbl_student.updated_at -INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
)
```

### Result: ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any suggestions to get the opposite result of second query and to combine with first?

any piece of code is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: MINUS operator of oracle. Anything similar would help right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table_instance x
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_other_table_instance y
    ON y.something = x.something
 WHERE y.something IS NULL
```

Comment: its not NULL condition i have to check. the second query returns some output, i need to avoid that results actually and i two tables to join. can i use same left join? what to use instead of is null as my result is not null?

Comment: The above method is not working. it is giving wrong answer as the condition is not null

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i found myself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, mobile, email 
  FROM tbl_student
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_class
    ON tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_staff
ON tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id
 WHERE tbl_student.upd_time <= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND fk_class_id NOT IN 
(SELECT fk_class_id 
  FROM tbl_student
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_class
    ON tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_staff
ON tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id
 WHERE
 tbl_staff.registered_at >= tbl_student.upd_time - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are checking tcl_staff.reg_time with pk_id in the subquery. Or You can use left join its simple and useful in this type.

```
SELECT Pk_class_id 
FROM tbl_student 
JOIN tbl_class on tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id 
JOIN tbl_staff on tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id 
WHERE tbl_staff.Pk_class_id
**NOT IN**
(
SELECT Pk_class_id 
FROM tbl_student 
JOIN tbl_class on tbl_student.fk_class_id = tbl_class.pk_class_id 
JOIN tbl_staff on tbl_staff.Pk_staff_id = tbl_class.fk_staff_id 
WHERE  tbl_staff.reg_time >= tbl_student.updated_at -INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
)
```